# If $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}:\ N_0\in S $ and $n+1\in S$ whenever $n\in S,$ then $S$ contains all natural numbers s.t. $n\geq N_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction

If $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}:\ N_0\in S $, **for some $N_0\in \mathbb{N}$**  and $n+1\in S$ whenever $n\in S,$ then $S$ contains all natural numbers s.t. $n\geq N_0$.

Considering the set $C$ that consists of $S$ together with all natural numbers, less than $N_0$ will be nice, but I can't see how to use this in showing that $S$ contains all natural numbers. Any help or hint will be highly appreciated in this regard.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you mean $S$ contains all natural numbers $n \geq N_0$? Otherwise the statement is not true.

Comment: @ZeroXLR: I've edited it. Can you show me why the former statement is false?

Comment: A counterexample is actually quite simple: $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N} :\ n > 2\}$.

Comment: @ZeroXLR: Thanks! Now that I've edited it. Any hints?

Comment: It depends. How much are you allowed to assume about the Natural Numbers? Are you only allowed to use Peano induction i.e. base case starts at $n = 0$?

Comment: @ZeroXLR: I'm re-studying using a book. Here, it requires induction.

Comment: What is its base case? Does it start from $n = 0$?

Comment: @ZeroXLR: It does starts from $n=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy the properties you defines. Now, let $S^\ast = \{n \in \mathbb{N}:\ n < N_0\}$. We show that $T = S \cup S^\ast$ contains all natural numbers by induction:

- **Base Case:** As $1$ is the least natural number $1 \leq N_0$. So either $1 = N_0 \in S$ or $1 < N_0$ implying $1 \in S^\ast$. Either way, $1 \in T$.
- **Inductive Step:** Suppose $n \in T$. Then either $n \in S$ or $n \in S^\ast$. If the former is the case, then by a property of $S$ that you defined we get $n + 1 \in S$. Otherwise if $n \in S^\ast$, then $n < N_0$. But, $n + 1$ is least natural number strictly larger than $n$; so we must have $n + 1 \leq N_0$. Then either $n + 1 = N_0 \in S$ or $n + 1 < N_0$ implying $N_0 \in S^\ast$. Either way, $n + 1 \in T$.

So by induction, $T$ contains all natural numbers. Now, we come to the main part: we show using what we established that $S$ contains all natural numbers $n \geq N_0$: Well, certainly $n \in S \cup S^\ast$ as $T$ contains all natural numbers. But, since $n \geq N_0$, we have $n \not< N_0$; so $n \notin S^\ast$. Thus, $n \in S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are good! Plus one!

Comment: I'll like to ask two questions but let me ask the first: How would the counter-example you provided have worked?

Comment: The counterexample was $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N}:\ n > 2\}$. $S$ contains $N_0 = 3$ and it satisfies if $n \in S$ then $n + 1 \in S$. And it does contain all elements $n \geq 3$. But, it **does not** contain all natural numbers because $2 \not\in S$ (since $2$ is not strictly greater than itself).